# Logstash, EC2 and elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elasticsearch, logstash

I have two elasticsearch nodes setup in EC2 and am trying to use logstash with it. I get this error when I run logstash:

```
log4j, [2014-02-24T10:45:32.722]  WARN: org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast: [Ishihara, Shirow] failed to send ping to [[#zen_unicast_1#][inet[/10.110.65.91:9300]]]
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: Failed to deserialize exception response from stream
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportSerializationException: Failed to deserialize exception response from stream
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:169)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:123)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
```

That's a snippet of it.
Here is the conf file I am using with logstash:

```
input {
  redis {
    host => "10.110.65.91"
    # these settings should match the output of the agent
    data_type => "list"
    key => "logstash"

    # We use the 'json' codec here because we expect to read
    # json events from redis.
    codec => json
  }
}

output {
  stdout { debug => true debug_format => "json"}

  elasticsearch {
  host => "10.110.65.91"
  cluster => searchbuild
        }
}
~
```

I'm running Logstash on .91 (have a second terminal window open) Am I missing something?

Comment: IS your java version the same on both nodes? http://jontai.me/blog/2013/06/elasticsearch-remotetransportexception-failed-to-deserialize-exception-response-from-stream/

Comment: Yes. I'm very new to Logstash. From what I understand I should have a third server that acts as the "indexer" and the other are "shippers", correct"?

Comment: I fixed it. I had to change "elasticsearch" to "elasticsearch_http"

Comment: I have a similar problem: logstash does not start automatically anymore after a problem of elasticsearch that has been fixed, I have created a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31586223/3062311), can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

I had to change "elasticsearch" to "elasticsearch_http".

Fixed.

Comment: This doesn't solve the original issue if you want to connect to elasticsearch not through HTTP requests.